# Recovering after exception when using a single dbcontext

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, dbcontext

I am using entity framework to persist data in a N-tier Wpf application. My dbcontext is shared amongst all repositories and is never disposed. When I persist data I mark an object as modifed and try to save changes. If an error accurs while persisting the object the object is still markted as modifed and if the user aborts the current opperation he will get the same error when saving another object.

I have solved this by overriding SaveChanges in my dbcontext and if any error accurs I accept all changes(see code below). So if an error accurs the object and all objects are marked unchanged even if theyr'e not persited.

This doesn't feel right...
Does anyone agree with this solution?
*Another solution would be to new the dbcontext in each method in my repositores and disposing of them right away. That will make my repositories more complicated and "noicy" and I will also lose the ability to lazy load data...*
Does anyone have a different solution for me?

```
    //In my repositories
    public void UpdateObject(Object object)
    {
        dbContext.Entry(object).State = EntityState.Modified;
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    //In my dbcontext class
    private ObjectContext ObjectContext()
    {
        return (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        try
        {
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            ObjectContext().AcceptAllChanges();
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our team uses an approach similar to below:

Repository:

```
public class StudentRepository
{
    private readonly MyEntities _context;

    public StudentRepository(MyEntities context)
    {
    _context = context;
    }

    // Basic CRUD methods etc
}
```

Business Logic:

```
public AddStudent(Student student)
{
    using( var context = new MyEntities())
    {
        var studentrepo = new StudentRepository(context);
        studentrepo.Add(student);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

This is an oversimplified example, but should give you an idea. To reduce code, we also use a base generic repository class for the CRUD methods.

If the project we are working on includes a web service, we instantiate the dbcontext in the API Controller and override the Dispose method to get rid of it.

Comment: Thinks for your answear :)
I have thought about your solution and for me it doesn't work well. I am using TDD and dependency injeciton.
The repos are sent in through constructor injection in my business logic. With your solution I would have to have a factory for the dbcontext and a factory for each repository.
This feels like overcomplicating the business logic and concerning the business logic with matters which don't concern them...

Comment: In the business logic above, the dbcontext and repositories can be both be passed through constructor injection. Like I mentioned in my answer, this is just a simplified example. If you do some research on Google using keywords such as dbcontext scope lifetime, you will find that most ppl recommend having a short lived context. In my own experience, we found a bug where someone had forgotten to dispose of a context and it caused a 50ms query on the webservice to take 3.2 minutes to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Having such a long lived context is not a good idea. It will get large and slow with all the entities and changes being tracked, concurrency related issues may arise and exceptions thrown by your context can impact your entire application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737

> Another solution would be to new the dbcontext in each method in my
>   repositores and disposing of them right away. That will make my
>   repositories more complicated and "noicy" and I will also lose the
>   ability to lazy load data

In a disconnected scenario I would create and dispose with each request/unit of work. Concerned about your repos getting complicated? Then don't use this extra layer of abstraction. Are the repos really necessary? What do you gain over using the DbContext directly?

As for lazy loading I think in a disconnected n-tier scenario that lazy loading is not really appropriate. You should probably use eager loading of required data for your view or have separate method calls to get the related data.

Comment: Thinks for your answear :)
To clearify my db layer is serperate and I don't expose anything from entity framework. I only expose poco objects(code first) so I could easily change my db layer. I am using the db layer in a wpf client and plan on using it in a web application and web services. In the latter scenarios it is easy to dispose of the context after each request.
My concern is the code duplication of newing and disposing of the context and performance.
Do you still think you solution is the best for me?
In the link you sent it is stated "one dbcontext per form" which could work?